# Interthread Communication program

Tags: java

```
Class Producer implements Runnable
   Q q;

   Producer(Q q) {
      this.q = q; // line- 5
      new Thread(this, "Producer").start();
   }
   public void run(){
      int i = 0;
      while(true){
         q.put(i++);
      }
   }
}
```

Hey can anyone please tell me :
1. At line 5, which q are these?
2. Why is, at line 6, no object is instantiated? Directly the start function is called?
Thanks...

Comment: This is likely to be a good way to kill your system. Depending on how it is implemented, q.put() is likely to create one or two objects per call causing your GC threads to max out. The default behaviour is to use all the cores on you system to do this. Unless you have very fast consumers you are likely to run out memory, which will at least stop the producer.

Answer (score 0):

**Line 5** - the q instance variable is set to whatever the value of q passed to Producers constructor is.

**Line 6** - A new Thread is instantiated.  It returns itself from the Constructor and the start method is immediately called.

Comment: in the main() function, new Producer(q) {where q is an object of Q) is written. Now my question is, what is the difference between this.q and q? this used to refer to the invoker? But here no object is invoking this constructor

Comment: the keyword this refers to the current Object instance - so it's referring to the instance variable, which is "Q q;"

Comment: Then
calling 
new Producer(q);
would be exactly the same as
Producer re = new Producer(q);
If so, then the 2nd way is useful for?

Comment: Yes - with the latter approach you retain a reference to the Producer in the re instance variable,  You'll often need this reference to work with the Object.

Answer (score 0):

- `this.q` is the instance variable `q` declared in line 2
- plain `q` is the constructor parameter declared in line 4
- In line 6, an object *is* instantiated via `new`, then the `start` method is immediately called on it. There just isn't any explicit reference to the object kept. However, since it was used to start a thread, it will be implicitly  referred to in that thread and thus doesn't become eligible for garbage collection until the thread finishes.

Comment: Then
calling 
new Producer(q);
would be exactly the same as
Producer re = new Producer(q);
If so, then the 2nd way is useful for?

Comment: @Abhay: the second way keeps a reference `re` to the object so you can call methods on it or pass it as parameter somwhere. Most objects are useless without a reference to them.

Answer (score 0):

At line 5, the class' private (this.)q is instantiated with the q passed in the constructor.

At line 6, a new Thread is created but the object is never used again, so it's just a short way of doing this.

```
  Thread t = new Thread(this,"Producer");
  t.start();
```

Is equivalent to

```
  new Thread(this,"Producer").start();
```

Comment: Then
calling 
new Producer(q);
would be exactly the same as
Producer re = new Producer(q);
If so, then the 2nd way is useful for?

Comment: new Producer(q) just makes a producer. You cannot use the object in any later part of your code in that case. This is fine if you do not need it. If you need the object (in your case 're') later on, you would use that second way!

Answer (score 0):

1. In the statement `this.q = q;`, `this.q` refers to the `q` field of the instance of the class, while `q` refers to the parameter.
2. `new Thread(this, "Producer")` creates a new instance of the `Thread` class so yes, an object is instantiated before calling the `start()` method.

Answer (score 0):

At line 5, `this.q` refers to the field `q` of the `Producer` object that is currently constructed. The second `q` refers to the constructor argument, i.e. the `Q` that has been passed to the construtor.

On line 6, there **is** a new `Thread` object constructed. It's just not assigned to any variable. Instead the `start()` method is directly called. This is a common pattern when no reference to the `Thread` object is required.

You *could* replace it with this equivalent code:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(this, "Producer");
thread.start();
```

That would have the exact same effect.

Comment: Then
calling 
new Producer(q);
would be exactly the same as
Producer re = new Producer(q);
If so, then the 2nd way is useful for?

Comment: @Abhay: the second way is the more common one, because *usually* an object doesn't actually *do* anything unless you call methods on it. This means that usually you'd want to keep a reference to it in a variable. The `Thread` is slightly different here: once you called `start()` it will run on its own. You *only* need to hold on to it, if you later need to check it's state, or something similar.